# Airflow : Skip a task using Branching

Tags: airflow

In my DAG wanted to skip a Task (oracle_merge_hist_orig)  depend on a flag.

My logic is:

when oracle_branch=True execute [merge_op,update_table_op,table_count_op]

when oracle_branch=False execute [update_table_op, table_count_op]

I tried to use BranchPythonOperator as follows:

```
args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
}
oracle_branch = True
def branch_func():
    if oracle_branch:
        return "oracle_branch"
    else:
        return "normal_branch"

dag = DAG(
    dag_id='example_branch_operator',
    default_args=args,
    schedule_interval="@daily",
)

branching_op = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branch_shall_run_oracle_merge_original_hist',
    python_callable=branch_func,
    dag= dag)

oracle_branch = DummyOperator(
    task_id='oracle_branch',
    dag=dag)

normal_branch = DummyOperator(
    task_id='normal_branch',
    dag=dag)

merge_op = DummyOperator(
    task_id='oracle_merge_hist_orig',
    dag=dag,
)

update_table_op = DummyOperator(
    task_id='update_table_job',
    dag=dag,
)

table_count_op = DummyOperator(
    task_id='table_count',
    dag=dag,
)

branching_op >> [oracle_branch,normal_branch] 
normal_branch >> update_table_op >> table_count_op
oracle_branch >> merge_op >> update_table_op >> table_count_op
```

However ,instead of skipping the Task it skips the entire path.

How to fix this so that I only skip the "racle_merge_hist_orig" task ?

When oracle_branch=False
[image]

when oracle_branch=True
[image]

Comment: Which Airflow version are you using?. I tested the same code in Airflow 1.8 and it is working correctly.

Comment: @SaiKiranNeelakantam I use version 1.10.3

Comment: I was able to reproduce your error on Airflow 1.10.4 and posted an answer below which will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Every task will have a `trigger_rule` which is set to `all_success` by default. We can override it to different values that are listed [here](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules).

In your DAG, the `update_table_job` task has two upstream tasks. Since one of its upstream task is in `skipped` state, it also went into `skipped` state. We can avoid this by overriding the default value of `trigger_rule` to **`one_success`** like below.

```py
update_table_op = DummyOperator(
    task_id='update_table_job',
    trigger_rule='one_success',
    dag=dag
)
```

[image]
**Note:** I tested this on Airflow 1.10.4 version.